# Get current path with name of query params in the path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Rails controller, how can I access my current path, but with the query params in the same format as what we have in `rails routes` ?

So for example, in [www.test.com/record/3](http://www.test.com/record/3) the helper I'm looking for would return `record/:id`.

I've tried `request.path` but it does not return the name of the param in the URL. It returns the actual path, which is not what I want.

Comment: assuming you know the param name, and it is used to be not dynamic. You can be sure to put the parameter name on a const. If you expect to receive `record/:id` you can pretty sure to have the key `id`. Perhaps `params.keys.slice(2..).map(&:to_sym)` helps you to fetch the params name.

Comment: How did you define the route in your `config/routes.rb`? Because I would a route like `record/3` to return `:controller/:id` in your example.

Comment: Why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are called [dynamic segments](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments) (or sometimes named placeholders).

You can get the them programatically for a given request with `request.path_parameters.except(:action, :controller)`.

```
# route is defined as 'get /:foo/:bar'
irb(main):013:0> app.get '/a/b?x=2'
Started GET "/a/b?x=2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-01-11 01:08:53 +0100
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Parameters: {"x"=>"2", "foo"=>"a", "bar"=>"b"}
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 7)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 2.7ms | Allocations: 2363)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.3ms | Allocations: 2675)


=> 200
irb(main):014:0> app.request.path_parameters
=> {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home", :foo=>"a", :bar=>"b"}
```

Unlike the params object this doesn't contain parameters from the query string or request body.